# Label expression in ArcGIS gives TypeError coercing to Unicode need string or buffer NoneType found?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser, expression

I try to build stacked label expression in ArcGis  10.3.1 with this expression:

```
[name3] + '\n'+ [results]
```

[image]

name3 and results are two columns in the attribute table. But I get this error:

```
typeerror coercing to unicode need string or buffer nonetype found
```

I read [Building label expressions - Expression examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm#GUID-47151603-A0B0-410E-90E6-D50F814888F1) but didn't find any solution.

This is the attribute table:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set to Python parser?

Comment: you're mixing your parsers.. with a vb parser you need to use vbNewLine: [name3] & vbNewLine & [results] or change to python parser.

Comment: Looks like you need to take a second look at what field types you are trying to merge. If not both are string, you might also need `str()`.

Comment: I think this part of the error `nonetype found` hints at what may be astray.  I think there is at least one <null> value in one or other field and when the Python parser gets to that it says that it cannot concatenate a `nonetype` (i.e. a <null>).

Comment: @PolyGeo I've been testing that, but I can't generate the same error when concatenating Nulls.  I'm trying to figure how `coercing to unicode need string ` comes into it here

Comment: @Midavalo Perhaps we need to see a short and narrow table with values that this fails on from the asker.

Comment: now i added an attribute table image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A value in one (or both) of your fields is a number, and python is trying to add it due to the `+` symbol, or alternatively it could be a value that can't be handled in its current form.  Either way you'll need to tell python that it's a string.  It is currently trying to use the value as unicode and it needs a string.

Using the Python Parser you need to use:

```py
"{}\n{}".format([name3], [results])
```

This will ensure that the values in your fields `name3` and `results` are treated as string in the label, even if the fields contain numbers.

Alternatively, if you're using the VB Parser you could use:

```vbs
[name3] & vbNewLine & [results]
```

Python Parser example:
[image]

VB Parser example:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
str([name3]) + '\n'+ str([results])
```

Convert your attributes to strings before joining.

Comment: but both of the fields definite as string

Comment: Did you try my answer?  Did it work?

Comment: it worked but i get also 'NONE' values in the lables

Comment: To eliminate the None values, you could just update your table on all empty values with an empty string with 2 single quotes '' (not a double quote). They won't appear anymore.

Comment: @newGIS - it may be because python is handling the null values as something other than a string.  You're better off using VB for simple expressions like this one.